# Separating values from XML using php with xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach

I need help from selecting data from XML. I can't seem to figure out the way xpath works with specific data selecting. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Value 1</c>
        <d>Value 2</d>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>Value 3</c>
        <d>Value 4</d>
    </b>
</a>
```

And PHP code i'm trying to use would be:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml"); 

$result = $xml->xpath('b/c | b/d');
foreach ($result as $val){
    echo $val['c'] . $val['d'] . "<br>;
}
```

If i echo `$val`, i get all values, however, i want to separate it so i have `$val['c']` and `$val['d']`, like when selecting specific data from MySQL table. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could just point to `b` first, then inside the loop, each `b`, point it to `c` and `d`:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//b');
foreach ($result as $val) {
    echo $val->c . $val->d . "<br>";
}
```